# Tensorflow CPU RAM allocation

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I experience an incredibly high amount of (CPU) RAM usage with Tensorflow while about every variable is allocated on the GPU device, and all computation runs there. Even then, RAM usage exceeds the VRAM usage by a factor of 2 at least.  I'm trying to understand why so as to see if it can be remedied or if it's inevitable.

## Question

So my main question is: **Does Tensorflow allocate and maintain a copy of all GPU variables on (CPU) RAM?** If yes, what is allocated when (in which phase, see below)? And why is it useful to allocate this in CPU memory?

#### More info

I have 3 phases in which I see RAM increasing dramatically.

1. First, when defining the graph (I append VGG-19 with quite large loss functions that iterate over many translated activation maps). This adds 2 GB to RAM usage.
2. Second, defining the optimizer (I use Adam) adds 250MB.
3. Initialize global variables adds 750MB.

And then it remains stable and runs very fast (all on GPU).
(Amounts of data mentioned here are when I input tiny images of size 8x8x3, batch size of 1. If I do more than 1x16x16x3, the process gets killed because it overflows my 8GB RAM+6GB swap limit).

Note that I recorded variable placement with tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True), and GPU usage using tf.RunMetadata and visualization on tensorboard.

Thank you for any help.

### System information

- Have I written custom code (as opposed to using a stock example script provided in TensorFlow): Yes
- OS Platform and Distribution: Linux Ubuntu 17.10
- TensorFlow installed from (source or binary): binary
- TensorFlow version (use command below): 1.7
- Python version: 3.6.3
- GCC/Compiler version (if compiling from source): 6.4.0
- CUDA/cuDNN version: 9.0
- GPU model and memory: NVidia GeForce Titan Xp

Comment: I'd guess TF would need to maintain the snapshots so it will need to copy the data through the RAM. It looks strange that you pair such a powerful GPU with such little RAM. I would probably just go out and buy more of RAM.

Comment: How are you feeding the data to the model? You might be producing more data on the input queue than your throughput on the GPU.

Comment: Run the tensorflow profiler, it's not hard to set up, post your results: https://towardsdatascience.com/howto-profile-tensorflow-1a49fb18073d?gi=97bda18e0bdf

Comment: Thanks for your comment @nikitautiu. However, there's no input data except for a single image (it's a texture synthesis network), e.g., in the trend of https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.07376. The only goal is to optimize the input image through backprop.

Comment: @Sorin: Agreed. Still, TF reports less data usage on the GPU than on the RAM. And I'm not certain of the usefulness of copying everything over to RAM if I don't save the network to disc. And especially the loss layers (which are my memory bottleneck) which don't get saved anyway.
I agree with your comment on RAM. I intend to buy more, but that still is not sufficient: as I said, it scales very badly to larger images, which I intend to use (e.g., 256x256).

Comment: @DavidParks good suggestion. I'm taking a look at that and will report on the result.

Comment: @DavidParks. Unfortunately, the profiler gives the same information as the tensorboard after logging a run with metadata, which is logging a session. My bottleneck is way before the start of a session, when defining the graph.

Comment: TensorFlow may pin some memory, especially variables, for more efficient copies. You can set the environmental variable `TF_CUDA_HOST_MEM_LIMIT_IN_MB`, but likely it'll just get you an error. AFAIK there's no way to tell it to pin less memory, just more with [`force_gpu_compatible`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/eaaee5d7aa5df8157c4128568a8f7703458723cd/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto#L73). You could file a feature request for less pinning.

Comment: I have observed analogous issue with repeated evaluation of new checkpoints during training. The CPU memory usage can grow as much as 60% over the course of hundreds of evaluation cycle from only 1-2% initially.